# Getting json response in php

Tags: php, json, curl

Does Php have a method that calls a Json URL, and save in a variable the data it fetches
for example can I used:
"https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/1/posts/"

I been trying with this code, but i am not sure if this is wrking

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/1/posts/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$df = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: "you're not sure this is working" well, then test it and tell us which is the EXACT problem you have. No connection? no data? wrong data? malformed data? how to parse the received data? at the moment it is not clear at all

Comment: the $df var has a true or false state, i expected the response data, i found the by google, and by that i dont understand at full what it does, that i seek help from coders who know what i wanted to do, and that part is clear, on top of that i been working with json for a short time, so as a started just wanted some help.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to achieve/which problem you have

Comment: and you took your time to down vote, while other for a change posted a solution, they did not seam to have a problem understanding,so once more i thank every one who came here to help

Comment: yes, but the other answer is on a completely different topic, so your question was not clear. And I'm not the only one that thinks so.

Comment: To make a word a better place, if u dont understand dont try to make a problem,because that does not help any 1,there are users who will get it.And we all do the best we can, and if that does not satisfy your needs, i am sorry, i did my best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the bulti-in function json_decode http://php.net/manual/it/function.json-decode.php

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/1/posts/");
$obj = json_decode($json); //returns an object of json values
$array = json_decode($json, true); //returns an array of json values
```

Comment: Actually, that will return an object, not an array.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is http*s*, try adding these:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a possible solution sir.